# Get single row depending of conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple select query with some joins like:

```
 SELECT
                 [c].[column1]
                , [c].[column2]
                 FROM [Customer] AS [c]
                     INNER JOIN ...
```

So I do a left join with my principal table as:

```
LEFT JOIN [Communication] AS [com] ON  [c].[CustomerGuid] = [com].[ComGuid]
```

this relatioship its 1 to *, one customer can have multiple communications

So in my select I want to get value 1 or 2 depending of condition:

Condition:

if ComTypeKey (from communication) table have a row with value 3 and  have another row with vale 4 return 1 then 0

So I try something like:

```
SELECT
                 [c].[column1]
                , [c].[column2]
                , IIF([com].[ComTypeKey] = 3 AND [com].[ComTypeKey] = 4,1,0)
                 FROM [Customer] AS [c]
                     INNER JOIN ...
                      LEFT JOIN [Communication] AS [com] ON  [c].[CustomerGuid] = [com].[ComGuid]
```

But it throws me two rows, beacause there are 2 rows on communication. My desire value is to get only one row with value 1 if my condition is true

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  However, if you want just one row, then `TOP (1)` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple rows you need `GROUP BY`, then count the relevant keys and subtract 1 to get (1, 0)

```
SELECT
    [c].[column1]
  , [c].[column2]
  ,  COUNT(CASE WHEN [ComTypeKey] IN (3,4) THEN 1 END) - 1  as FLAG_CONDITION
FROM [Customer] AS [c]
INNER JOIN ...
LEFT JOIN [Communication] AS [com] 
  ON  [c].[CustomerGuid] = [com].[ComGuid]
GROUP BY 
    [c].[column1]
  , [c].[column2]
```

Comment: It returns me result correctly problem is I still getting two rows

Comment: You shouldn't get two rows if are using `GROUP BY`. Show us some sample data and current result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand.

This will literally find if both values 3 and 4 exist for that CustomerGuid, and only select one of them in that case - not filtering out any record otherwise.

If this is not what you want, providing sample data with the expected result would remove the ambiguity.

```
SELECT Field1,
       Field2,
       ...
       FieldN
  FROM (SELECT TMP.*,
               CASE WHEN hasBothValues = 1 THEN 
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerGuid ORDER BY 1 )
                    ELSE 1
                END AS iterim_rn
          FROM (SELECT TD.*,
                       MAX(CASE WHEN Value1 = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                         ( PARTITION BY CustomerGuid ) *
                       MAX(CASE WHEN Value1 = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                         ( PARTITION BY CustomerGuid ) AS hasBothValues
                  FROM TEST_DATA TD
               ) TMP
       ) TMP2
 WHERE interim_rn = 1
```

Comment: You dont need a CASE just multiply `1*1 = 1` and `1*0 = 0*1 = 0*0 =0`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Hmmm, yeah that is cleaner. As far as an additional group by  I think we may be interpreting the question differently, but it's definitely possible.